# Selected by groups with totals (mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I've been fiddleing with this about 20 minutes now and though I might get some help here. I have two tables, in a many-to-one relationship. users (one) and events (many). The tables, simplified, look like this:

```
users
-----------
user_id
group_id

events
-----------
user_id
```

I'm trying to produce a report that will show the number of users with at least one event, per group. so a result set would hopefully look like:

```
group_id   users_with_at_least_one_event
1          689
2          312
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  group_id, count(*) users_with_at_least_one_event
FROM 
(
SELECT  u.user_id, u.group_id, count(*) as event_count
FROM    users u
        JOIN events e
        ON u.user_id = e.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.group_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
) sub
GROUP BY group_id
```

Comment: this works and has the advantage of allowing me to say "with more then 3 events" -- although it did require adding the table name to some of the column names to disambiguate

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right.  I forgot to prefix the fields with the table name aliases.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I fixed to get rid of the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select users.group_id, count(distinct users.user_id) as users_with_at_least_one_event
from 
users, events 
where users.user_id = events.user_id 
group by users.group_id
```

Comment: I think this isn't right as its returning 30K+ even though the group has 2700 members.

Comment: added `distinct` in the query, try that.

Comment: This just gives a count of the users in each group from the events table.

Comment: `users_with_at_least_one_event` is the count of `users` as per the name OP gave it. OP can change it to `count(distinct events)` , if thats what he/she wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.group_id, COUNT(*) FROM users 
WHERE users.user_id IN (SELECT events.user_id FROM events)
```

Comment: This is just returning a list of users that are in the events table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_id, COUNT(users.user_id) AS users_with_at_least_one_event,
FROM users, events
WHERE users.user_id = events.user_id
GROUP BY group_id
```

maybe?

Comment: This just gives a count of the users in each group from the events table.